Is it possible for some being to violate the laws of physics?
Is it possible for some being to violate the laws of physics? My belief is that it isn't possible for any being, no matter how powerful, to violate the laws of physics. Because, simply by definition, the laws of physics apply everywhere and at all times. But what have philosophers written about this matter?

If the "being" is not "natural", maybe.

A phenomenon which violates the laws of physics is named a “miracle”. Hence you ask about the possibility of miracles.

History of science knows several discoveries which show the limit of
existing scientific theories and scientific conceptions. But these
contradictions should not be mixed-up with miracles. Each theory has
a range where it applies. Within this range the theory makes a
general claim, excluding contradicting exceptions.
On the other hand, history knows many reports of miracles. Each
religion reports miraculous acts of its god or his devotees to
demonstrate the power of the god. But these reports are not
reliable, because they do not satisfy the requirements for a
historical source.

To sum up: Unbiased reliable reports of miracles do not exist. Each miracle would question one or more physical laws from the corresponding domain.

Kristian Berry's answer is good, but I think it may help to reduce the problem to its most boring form: definitions, identity, and noncontradiction.
Laws of physics has two meanings: the way things always behave; and the human attempts to guess the way things have behaved so far and predict the way they will behave in the future.
This question is therefore two different easy questions, one for each definition.
1: Can a thing behave other than the way it always behaves? No, this is a contradiction.
2: Are humans fallible? Yes.
If one wishes to define the laws of physics to only describe the way a part of reality behaves, then 1 becomes:
1a: is there a part of reality which behaves the way that part of reality behaves? Yes, this is an identity.
And if we don't know whether or not there is such a part, then 1 defaults to the question of whether reality has such parts:
1b: Is there is a part of reality which behaves the way that it would behave if it existed? If there is such a part, yes. Else no.
